# tensorflow TF-slim inceptionv3 training loss curve is strange

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

TF-slim inceptionv3 train from scratch

I use slim/train_image_classifier.py to train a inception_v3 model on my own dataset:
python train_image_classifier.py --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} --dataset_name=mydataset --dataset_split_name=train --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} --model_name=inception_v3 --num_clones=2

the loss curve was strange as the tensorboard shown, it was a linearly decreasing straight line with a little bump part.
[image]

the following are the last outputs, the loss was decreased 0.0001 every 20 or 30 steps：

```
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34590: loss = 0.5359 (1.17 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34600: loss = 0.5358 (1.15 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34590: loss = 0.5359 (1.17 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34600: loss = 0.5358 (1.15 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34610: loss = 0.5358 (1.17 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34620: loss = 0.5357 (1.12 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34630: loss = 0.5357 (1.16 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34640: loss = 0.5356 (1.16 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34650: loss = 0.5356 (1.16 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34660: loss = 0.5355 (1.15 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34670: loss = 0.5355 (1.15 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34680: loss = 0.5355 (1.18 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34690: loss = 0.5354 (1.17 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34700: loss = 0.5354 (1.15 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34710: loss = 0.5353 (1.15 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34720: loss = 0.5353 (2.25 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34730: loss = 0.5353 (2.22 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34740: loss = 0.5352 (1.16 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34750: loss = 0.5352 (1.16 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34760: loss = 0.5351 (1.18 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34770: loss = 0.5351 (1.15 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34780: loss = 0.5350 (1.17 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34790: loss = 0.5350 (1.15 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34800: loss = 0.5349 (1.12 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34810: loss = 0.5349 (1.12 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34820: loss = 0.5349 (1.16 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34830: loss = 0.5348 (1.16 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34840: loss = 0.5348 (1.18 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34850: loss = 0.5347 (1.12 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34860: loss = 0.5347 (1.12 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34870: loss = 0.5347 (1.18 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34880: loss = 0.5346 (1.13 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34890: loss = 0.5346 (1.18 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34900: loss = 0.5345 (1.16 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34910: loss = 0.5345 (1.15 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34920: loss = 0.5344 (1.17 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34930: loss = 0.5344 (1.14 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34940: loss = 0.5344 (1.15 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34950: loss = 0.5343 (1.14 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 34960: loss = 0.5343 (1.17 sec/step)
```

mydataset.py is the same as flowers.py except:

```
SPLITS_TO_SIZES = {'train': 18000000, 'validation': 400000}
 _NUM_CLASSES = 4
```

Is it normal? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are plotting the graph for total loss after n steps(which is probably number_of_steps if you are using tf.contrib.slim train method) in your training while the loss thats logged is for every 10 steps. 
Hope this helps!